# Correct syntax for @foreach on Razor page where value can be equal to more than one thing

Tags: asp.net, arraylist, foreach, razor-pages

I need assistance with getting the syntax correct for this code on my razor page:

```
@foreach (var officerGroup in Model.Results
                                   .Where(i => i.InvestType in ("YO", "CRD", "PPI", "PSI")
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.ProbOfficer))
```

Basically, I want to filter by a specific subset of `InvestType` values in this particular section of a report. There are other values for `InvestType` that I DON'T wish to include. I don't know how to do an "in" type of statement.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Should be able to make a list of only the InvestTypes you want (so `var yourList = new List<string> { "YO", "CRD", ...`) and do something like `.Where(i => yourList.Contains(i.InvestType))`

Comment: Thank you. I haven't made a static list before, so not sure what I put in the place of 'string' in your example? Since it's a static, hard-coded list, I wouldn't be referencing a model.

Comment: `string` is just defining the type the list is.  Based off of your code example, `InvestType` is a string, so your list must also be.

Comment: I put this in my OnPost on the .cs: var fullReportList = new List<string> { "CRD", "PPI", "PSI", "Supvsn Only", "TO" }; and this on my .cshtml page: @foreach (var officerGroup in Model.Results.Where(i => fullReportList.Contains(i.InvestType)).GroupBy(x => x.ProbOfficer)) but get an error: CS0103: The name 'fullReportList' does not exist in the current context. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to declare it on the .cshtml page too?

Comment: Or do I need to put it int a separate outer @foreach(var fullReportList... around the @foreach(var officerGroup...?

Comment: The outer @foreach seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@{ ... }` to declare variables inside a `.cshtml` file:

```
@{
    var fullReportList = new List<string> { "CRD", "PPI", "PSI", "Supvsn Only", "TO" };
}

@foreach (var officerGroup in Model.Results
                                   .Where(i => fullReportList.Contains(i.InvestType))
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.ProbOfficer))
{

}
```

Or you can add it in your `PageModel` like this:

```
public class DemoModel : PageModel
{
    public List<string> FullReportList => new() { "CRD", "PPI", "PSI", "Supvsn Only", "TO" };

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

and in the `.cshtml`:

```
@foreach (var officerGroup in Model.Results
                                   .Where(i => Model.FullReportList.Contains(i.InvestType))
                                   .GroupBy(x => x.ProbOfficer))
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was close with the outer foreach, just didn't realize I didn't have to wrap the other foreach. Thank you for explaining how to put it in my .cs!!